# Gamma function residue

Tags: complex-analysis

I have derived that:

$\displaystyle\Gamma(z)=\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}=\frac{1}{z}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^ze^{-t} dt$

where the real part of $z$, Re$(z)>-1$, $z \neq 0$

How do I find the residue of $z$ at $0$?

Comment: Since the pole is simple, you have $\operatorname{Res}(\Gamma; 0) = \lim_{z\to 0} z\cdot\Gamma(z)$.

Comment: Is it Gamma(1)?

Comment: yes. $\Gamma(\epsilon) = \frac{\Gamma(1+\epsilon)}{\epsilon} \sim \frac{\Gamma(1)}{\epsilon}$ when $\epsilon \to 0$. hence the residue $Res(\Gamma,0)$ is $\Gamma(1) = 1$

Comment: Yes. Can this be found directly from the definition of residue or does it require the formula used by @DanielFischer?

Comment: Which definition of the residue do you use?

Comment: @DanielFischer The coefficient of the $n=-1$ term in the Laurent series

Comment: Then just expand $\int_0^{\infty} t^z e^{-t}\,dt$ in its Maclaurin series.

Comment: and the definition of Daniel has nothing exraordinnary. remember only the  definition : coef $c_{-1}$ in the Laurent series , then if $f(z)$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0$ the Laurent series is $f(z) = \sum_{k=-m}^\infty c_k (z-z_0)^k$ and you get $c_{-1} = \frac{1}{(m-1)!} g^{(m-1)}(z_0)$ with $g(z) = (z-z_0)^m f(z)$.